# Function results only lasting a millisecond

Tags: javascript

Im just getting into javascript and Im writing a script thats supposed to hide a submit button and show a similiar button which shows the site is processing the info. The fucntion below gets the result im looking for but only for a millisecond before returning to normal. Im not sure if the fuction is incorrect or if I have to add a sleep command or something.

```
<form>
  <input placeholder="ID"><br>
  <button id="submit" onclick="send()" type="">Submit</button>
  <button id="loading"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i> Submiting</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function send() {
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    var loading = document.getElementById('loading');

    if (submit.style.display === "none") {
      loading.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      submit.style.display = "none";
      loading.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you verify that this is the actual code being used, and that you don't have a `input` with a type `submit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Submit" button submits the form, which requests it again and renders the original version. To prevent this first add a parameter to your `send()` function which holds the data above the event:

```
function send(event)
```

Now add the following line at the end of your function:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

This prevents the form from being submitted.

Comment: Doesn't the button need to have the `type` of `submit` for that to be the case?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, I was considering that as I typed this up. I can't think of any other reason right now for the behavior described by the OP.

Comment: I just tested your solution and it worked! thanks :D